# Using ruby array each display into single textarea?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array in my ruby like the following:

```
[#<Order::List code: 1511, Reference: "FRIA004", valuation: nil, full_Address: "1, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "1 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very low">,
 #<Order::List code: 1512, Reference: "FRIA005", valuation: nil, full_Address: "2, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "2 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very high, 3 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very low">,
 #<Order::List code: 1513, Reference: "FRIA006", valuation: nil, full_Address: "3, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "15 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Low">,
 #<Order::List code: 1514, Reference: "FRIA007", valuation: nil, full_Address: "6, abc road, xyz", reason_available: "Y", list: "16 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - High">]
```

### Model:

```
class Order::List < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :Code

  def self.display_details(codes)
    codes.each { |x|
      details = Order::List.where(Code: x).first
      reference = details.Reference
      address = details.full_Address
      list = details.list

      display_details = reference + "\n" + address + "\n" + list
      return display_details
  end
end
```

### View:

So I can display the detail list into the textarea like the following:

```
<%= f.text_area :detail_list, rows: 8, value: (Order::List.display_details(codes)) %>
```

### Output:

```
FRIA004
1, abc road, xyz
2 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very high, 3 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very low
```

### Questions:

1) It has been stopped after return the first `code`. I am using `each` and want to display each of the `code` into the `text_area`

2) How can I display the list(list is the column here) into the new line after the comma?

### So my expected output is

```
FRIA004
1, abc road, xyz
1 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very low

FRIA005
2, abc road, xyz
2 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very high
3 : Meter cupboard generic throughout - Very low
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 1: `return` ends processing of the method and returns the value. So you should do something like:

```
def self.display_details(codes)
  retval = ""
  codes.each do |x| 
    .......
    display_details = reference + "\n" + address + "\n" + list + '\n'
    .......
    retval << display_details
  end
  return retval
end
```

ad 2: Just add `\n` to the end of every line:

```
display_details = reference + "\n" + address + "\n" + list + '\n'
```

Comment: Thank you. How can i make the `list` into the new line. Please have a look at my expected output.

Comment: Well, you can collect and return the string, not the list. I will edit my answer

Comment: Hi, can you give me some example to collect and return the string please?

Comment: Sorry, I have asked to return the list value into new lines. `E.g:  1: Meter cupboard very low, 2: Meter cupboard very high` into new lines?

Answer (score 1):

```
codes.map do |x|
  details   = Order::List.where(Code: x).first
  reference = details.Reference
  address   = details.full_Address
  list      = details.list

  "#{reference}\n#{address}\n#{list}\n"
end
```

By the way, it is not your model responsibility to present data. Should be done in a view partial or a presenter.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. How can i display the each of the list separated by comma into the newline?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `map` or `collect` instead of `each`.